# MySQL 8: Problems when granting privileges on new user

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm using a fresh installation of MySQL 8.0.31 on Ubuntu 22.04.1, and I've been following the instructions in [an article by Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-22-04).

I created a new user:

`CREATE USER 'sammy'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` and then proceeded to grant privileges:

`GRANT CREATE, ALTER, DROP, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT, REFERENCES, RELOAD on *.* TO 'sammy'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

At this point, I get an error:

> ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT

I'm not creating a user, so I have no idea what's happening here.

When I attempt to drop the user:

`DROP USER waynesmallman` or: `DROP USER waynesmallman@localhost` or: `DROP USER 'waynesmallman'@'%'`

I get an error:

> ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'waynesmallman'@'%'

I was asked by @akina to run: `SHOW GRANTS;` and share the results:

> +--+ | Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
> +--+ | GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES,
> SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION
> SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE,
> ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE
> ROLE, DROP ROLE ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION
> | | GRANT
> APPLICATION_PASSWORD_ADMIN,AUDIT_ABORT_EXEMPT,AUDIT_ADMIN,AUTHENTICATION_POLICY_ADMIN,BACKUP_ADMIN,BINLOG_ADMIN,BINLOG_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,CLONE_ADMIN,CONNECTION_ADMIN,ENCRYPTION_KEY_ADMIN,FIREWALL_EXEMPT,FLUSH_OPTIMIZER_COSTS,FLUSH_STATUS,FLUSH_TABLES,FLUSH_USER_RESOURCES,GROUP_REPLICATION_ADMIN,GROUP_REPLICATION_STREAM,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ARCHIVE,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ENABLE,PASSWORDLESS_USER_ADMIN,PERSIST_RO_VARIABLES_ADMIN,REPLICATION_APPLIER,REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,SENSITIVE_VARIABLES_OBSERVER,SERVICE_CONNECTION_ADMIN,SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN,SET_USER_ID,SHOW_ROUTINE,SYSTEM_USER,SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN,TABLE_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,XA_RECOVER_ADMIN
> ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION | | GRANT PROXY ON
> `@` TO `root`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION
> |
> +--+

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Your **current** account was created/granted without `WITH GRANT OPTION` - so you cannot create another user with this option.

Comment: I'm trying to grant privileges to the user I've created, not create another user.

Comment: Your current account (the account which you use now, not one which you try to grant) have no WITH GRANT  option.

Comment: MySQL created the root account, not me — how do I fix this?

Comment: Execute `SHOW GRANTS;` and add the output into your question text as an update.

Comment: Do you have access to the 'root' account or any other account with 'SUPER' proviledge?

Comment: Hi @RickJames, I was signed in as root when creating the user, and attempting to grant privileges, but Akina seems to think there's a problem with the root account.